# Select second min() or second smallest from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm wondering how to select the second smallest value from a mysql table, grouped on a non-numeric column. If I have a table that looks like this:

```
    +----+----------+------------+--------+------------+
    | id | customer | order_type | amount | created_dt |
    +----+----------+------------+--------+------------+
    |  1 |        1 | web        |      5 | 2017-01-01 |
    |  2 |        1 | web        |      7 | 2017-01-05 |
    |  3 |        2 | web        |      2 | 2017-01-07 |
    |  4 |        3 | web        |      2 | 2017-02-01 |
    |  5 |        3 | web        |      3 | 2017-02-01 |
    |  6 |        2 | web        |      5 | 2017-03-15 |
    |  7 |        1 | in_person  |      7 | 2017-02-01 |
    |  8 |        3 | web        |      8 | 2017-01-01 |
    |  9 |        2 | web        |      1 | 2017-04-01 |
    +----+----------+------------+--------+------------+
```

I want to count the number of second orders in each month/year. I also have a customer table (which is where the customer ids come from). I can find the number of customers with more than at least 2 orders by the customer's created date by querying

```
select date(c.created_dt) as create_date, count(c.id) 
from customer c 
where c.id in 
  (select or.identity_id 
  from orders or 
  where 
    (select count(o.created_dt) 
    from orders o 
    where or.customer = o.customer and o.order_tpe in ('web')
    ) > 1
  ) 
group by 1;
```

However, that result gives customer by their created date, and I can't seem to figure out how to find the the number of second orders by date.
The desired output i'd like to see, based on the data above, is:

```
    +-------+------+---------------+
    | month | year | second_orders |
    +-------+------+---------------+
    |  1    | 2017 | 1             |
    |  2    | 2017 | 1             |
    |  3    | 2017 | 1             |
    +-------+------+---------------+
```

Comment: can you clarify what second orders mean?

Comment: I think OP means how many times did a customer order AT LEAST twice in a month.

Comment: @vkp the second time that a customer ordered. From the sample data set, there was 1 second order in Jan '17, 1 in Feb '17 & 1 in Mar '17

Comment: Can you post the desired output based on the sample data?

Comment: @peterm updated my question to show the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this

```sql
SELECT YEAR(created_dt) year, MONTH(created_dt) month, COUNT(*) second_orders
  FROM (
    SELECT created_dt,
           @rn := IF(@c = customer, @rn + 1, 1) rn,
           @c := customer
      FROM orders CROSS  JOIN (
        SELECT @c := NULL, @rn := 1
      ) i
     WHERE order_type = 'web'
     ORDER BY customer, id
  ) q
 WHERE rn = 2
 GROUP BY YEAR(created_dt), MONTH(created_dt)
 ORDER BY year, month
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=c126e3dbf4fb5f9c2b3eb69368b2b2ba) demo

Output:

```
+------+-------+---------------+
| year | month | second_orders |
+------+-------+---------------+
| 2017 |     1 |             1 |
| 2017 |     2 |             1 |
| 2017 |     3 |             1 |
+------+-------+---------------+
```

Comment: Also, thanks for showing me dbfiddle, I knew about jsfiddle but didn't know there was a db version!